# JOSE ConfigurableJWTProcessor Issue

Tags: spring, jose

I'm getting this error when I try to process a JWT using ConfigurableJWTProcessor:

```
Required JOSE header typ (type) parameter is missing
```

I've already set the **typ** parameter in the header as it's specified in the docs but it doesn't work: https://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-jose-jwt/examples/validating-jwt-access-tokens

Here is the method where I configure the JwtProcessor:

```
 private void configureJwtProcessor() throws MalformedURLException {
        jwtProcessor = new DefaultJWTProcessor<>();

        jwtProcessor.setJWSTypeVerifier(
                new DefaultJOSEObjectTypeVerifier<>(new JOSEObjectType("id_token+jwt"))); // Setting the "typ" header 
        
        String jwkUrl = String.format(this.cognitoConfiguration.getJwkUrl(),
                this.cognitoConfiguration.getRegion(), this.cognitoConfiguration.getUserPoolId());

        String issuer = String.format(this.cognitoConfiguration.getIssuerUrl(),
                this.cognitoConfiguration.getRegion(), this.cognitoConfiguration.getUserPoolId());

        JWKSource<SecurityContext> keySource = JWKSourceBuilder
                .create(new URL(jwkUrl))
                .retrying(true)
                .build();

        JWSAlgorithm expectedJWSAlg = JWSAlgorithm.RS256;

        JWSKeySelector<SecurityContext> keySelector = new JWSVerificationKeySelector<>(
                expectedJWSAlg,
                keySource);

        jwtProcessor.setJWSKeySelector(keySelector);
        jwtProcessor.setJWTClaimsSetVerifier(new DefaultJWTClaimsVerifier<>(
                new JWTClaimsSet.Builder().issuer(issuer).build(),
                new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(
                        JWTClaimNames.SUBJECT,
                        JWTClaimNames.ISSUED_AT,
                        JWTClaimNames.EXPIRATION_TIME,
                        "scp",
                        "cid",
                        "cognito:groups",
                        JWTClaimNames.JWT_ID))));
    }
```